# Spree Multi Vendor Marketplace controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am working on a little project with spree + multi-vendor marketplace gem. I want to create an index and view for each vendor like https://spree-multi-vendor-marketplace.com/vendors and https://spree-multi-vendor-marketplace.com/vendors/c-amare#.

Its more than a little frustrating that this isn't core to the plugin, as it seems very basic.

It is my first time with spree and I can't see controllers. I cant see how to generate them in the documentation so I So I created a controller 
app/controllers/spree/vendors_controller.rb

```
module Spree
  class VendorsController
    def index
    end
    def show
    end
  end
end
```

I added the route in config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # This line mounts Spree's routes at the root of your application.
  # This means, any requests to URLs such as /products, will go to
  # Spree::ProductsController.
  # If you would like to change where this engine is mounted, simply change the
  # :at option to something different.
  #
  # We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Spree relies on it being
  # the default of "spree".
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end

Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :vendors 
end
```

I have added a blank view for testing app/views/spree/vendors/index.html.erb

now I am getting undefined method `binary_params_for?' for Spree::VendorsController:Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spree multi-vendor uses a stores controller so we have to call from it in our controller.

```
module Spree
  class VendorsController < Spree::StoreController
    def index
      @vendors = Spree::Vendor.all
    end
    def show
    end
  end
```

end

I added that and I now have an index page. :) I hope this is helpful